# vb.net: how to define a UI control's event handler sub in a module, and not in the form with the UI control

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I want my user interface event handler to be in a module, and not in my user interface form.

For example, I added a button to my form.
At design time, I double clicked it and then moved the resulting handler sub to a module file.

But now a red squiggly underlines "_MainForm.Button_settings_account_save.Click" in the handler sub and shows this error:
'Handles' in modules must specify a 'WithEvents' variable qualified with a single identifier

```
    Private Sub Button_settings_account_save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _MainForm.Button_settings_account_save.Click   
          stop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [AddHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93(v=vs.90).aspx) approach instead of letting the WinForms designer add the *Handles* to your button click method.

In the form constructor, after the call to InitialzeComponents or in the Form_Load event handler you could add

```
AddHandler Button_settings_account_save.Click, AddressOf YourModuleName.YourEventHandlerMethod
```

Comment: Yes, and remove `Handles _MainForm.Button_settings_account_save.Click` from the event handler.